# Kover - Unable to use excludes as mentioned in Docs

Tags: android, kotlin, code-coverage, kover

Tried the Android code as given in the [Docs](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-kover#configuring-jvm-test-task).

I am unable to exclude the files.

```
testOptions {
      unitTests.all {
          if (name == "testDebugUnitTest") {
              kover {
                  disabled = false
                  binaryReportFile.set(file("$buildDir/custom/debug-report.bin"))
                  // includes = ['com.example.*']
                  excludes = [
                          "com.makeappssimple.abhimanyu.financemanager.android.navigation.di.NavigationManagerModule"
                  ]
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

I expect this code to exclude `com.makeappssimple.abhimanyu.financemanager.android.navigation.di.NavigationManagerModule` file, but it is not working.
Also tried with wildcard names.

Kover setup,

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "kotlin-kapt"
    id "dagger.hilt.android.plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlinx.kover" version "0.5.0"
}

// Kover
kover {
    disabled = false                        // true to disable instrumentation of all test tasks in all projects
    coverageEngine.set(kotlinx.kover.api.CoverageEngine.INTELLIJ) // change instrumentation agent and reporter
    intellijEngineVersion.set('1.0.656')    // change version of IntelliJ agent and reporter
    jacocoEngineVersion.set('0.8.7')        // change version of JaCoCo agent and reporter
    generateReportOnCheck = true            // false to do not execute `koverMergedReport` task before `check` task
    disabledProjects = []                   // ["project-name"] or [":project-name"] to disable coverage for project with path `:project-name` (`:` for the root project)
    instrumentAndroidPackage = false        // true to instrument packages `android.*` and `com.android.*`
    runAllTestsForProjectTask = false       // true to run all tests in all projects if `koverHtmlReport`, `koverXmlReport`, `koverReport`, `koverVerify` or `check` tasks executed on some project
}
```

P.S: I have also raised the same issue [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-kover/issues/177)

Comment: It looks like you closed your issue at the provided link https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-kover/issues/177 . If that sufficiently resolved your issue, you can self-answer this SO question and include any details that might be helpful to a future visitor to the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [shanshin](https://github.com/shanshin)'s [comment](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-kover/issues/177#issuecomment-1123331446), I understood the issue.

Fixed the unit test coverage report exclusion list using this code

```
tasks.koverHtmlReport {
    excludes = [
            // Hilt
            "*.di.*",
            "dagger.hilt.**",
            "hilt_aggregated_deps.*",
            "<package_name>.*.*_Factory",

            // Room
            // MyRoomDatabase_AutoMigration_*_Impl, *Dao_Impl
            "<package_name>.*.*_Impl*",

            // BuildConfig
            "<package_name>.BuildConfig",

            // Moshi - Json Adapter
            "<package_name>.*.*JsonAdapter",
    ]
}
```

The exclusion list mentioned in the question is to exclude tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to add a filter the kover plugin like this *`version 0.6.0`*

```
kover {
    instrumentation {
        excludeTasks.add("testReleaseUnitTest")
    }

    filters {
        classes {
            excludes += listOf(
                "dagger.hilt.internal.aggregatedroot.codegen.*",
                "hilt_aggregated_deps.*",
                "*ComposableSingletons*",
                "*_HiltModules*",
                "*Hilt_*",
                "*BuildConfig",
                ".*_Factory.*",
            )
        }
    }
}
```